# SoundTrap is not appearing in ST Host

Tags: soundtrap, computer, usb, soundtraphost

I recently plugged in a ST600 into my computer, and it would not show up in ST Host.  I followed the instructions (removed the batteries and ST cards) to troubleshoot the issue as outlined in the manual, but this did not work. However, when I plugged the ST600 into a different computer, it appeared in ST Host and worked fine.

Additionally, for the computer that could not connect with the ST600, I had recently tried to resurrect a ST500 with that computer. The internal battery on that unit was dead, and therefore needed to be plugged in overnight in order to charge. It did not show up in the ST Host. Even after charging, that ST500 ALSO did not appear on the computer I had charged it at, but was able to connect to a different computer no issue. It appears that after I tried to connect that ST500, I could not connect any other ST to that computer. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

So, while I am unsure how this issue started (if it was related to the ST500 or not), I was able to fix it by resetting my USB drivers.  I had tried to uninstall and reinstall ST Host, and restart the computer, but that did not work.  What worked was this:

- Go to Device Manager
- Open USB controllers menu
- Select Host Controller
- Right-click, uninstall device
- Restart computer.

[image: screenshot of Device Manager following the steps above]

You may need to play around with what device you uninstall, but the restart will reinstall your drivers.  After this, I was able to get any Soundtrap to connect to ST Host again.

Word to the wise: have a back up mouse and keyboard on hand if your mouse and keyboard are connected via USB. Learn from my mistakes!

Comment: This is a common 'feature' of Windows PC that USB ports can get 'locked' or even 'corrupted'. The suggested procedure is indeed the windows way to unmount and allow Plug-and Play to remount the device. It may be necessary to Unhide the USB ports in case the device is not plugged in. Windows remenbers the device and simply unplugging and replugging does not work once the device is corrupted.

Comment: Restarting the computer may not be necessary, only unplugging and replugging the device, but restarting the computer is always a good method to remove 'zombies'